# Querying Mongo when a document have one to many relationship in a single well structed query using mongo C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, mongodb-query

I'll try to explain it as simple as possible.

We have these 5 very simple classes. Any class that not end with the DTO suffix represent a real document living inside a mongo collection.

```
public class TruckSingleDriver
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string DriverId { get; set; }
}

public class TruckSingleDriverDTO
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public Driver Driver { get; set; }
}


public class TruckManyDrivers
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> DriversIds { get; set; }
}

public class TruckManyDriversDTO
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Driver> Drivers { get; set; }
}

public class Driver
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

the simplest way to get TruckSingleDriverDTO with **one** query will be as follow:

```
public TruckSingleDriverDTO GetTruckSingleDriverDTO(string truckId)
{
    var truckCollection = mongo.GetDatabase("mydb").GetCollection<TruckSingleDriver>("Trucks");
    var driverCollection = mongo.GetDatabase("mydb").GetCollection<Driver>("Drivers");

    TruckSingleDriverDTO truckDTO = truckCollection.AsQueryable()
                                    .Where(truck => truck.Id == truckId)
                                    .Join(driverCollection, truck => truck.DriverId, driver => driver.Id,
                                          (truck, driver) => new { Id = truck.Id, Driver = driver })
                                    .ToEnumerable() //needed although it seems not
                                    .Select(res => new TruckSingleDriverDTO() { Id = res.Id, Driver = res.Driver })
                                    .Single();
    return truckDTO;
}
```

What i want to achieve is to get TruckManyDriversDTO in a **single** query, is there away to do it?

```
public TruckManyDriversDTO GetTruckManyDriversDTO(string truckId)
{
    var trucks = mongo.GetDatabase("mydb").GetCollection<TruckManyDrivers>("Trucks");
    var drivers = mongo.GetDatabase("mydb").GetCollection<Driver>("Drivers");

    /*
     * here i need your help 
     * keep in mind that i want it in a single query 
     * below this, ill show the simple way to achieve it with 2 queries
     */

    TruckManyDrivers truck = trucks.Find(t => t.Id == truckId).Single();
    IEnumerable<Driver> driverList = drivers.Find(d => truck.DriversIds.Contains(d.Id)).ToEnumerable();

    return new TruckManyDriversDTO() { Id = truck.Id, Drivers = driverList };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got help from this site: https://www.csharpschool.com/blog/linq-join

The best solution I could come up with:

```
    public TruckManyDriversDTO GetTruckManyDriversDTO(string truckId)
    {
        var Trucks = mongo.GetDatabase("mydb").GetCollection<TruckManyDrivers>("Trucks").AsQueryable();
        var Drivers = mongo.GetDatabase("mydb").GetCollection<Driver>("Drivers").AsQueryable();

        var query = from truck in Trucks where truck.Id == truckId
                    let truckDrivers = from driver in Drivers
                                       where truck.DriversIds.Contains(driver.Id) select driver
                                       select new { Truck = truck, Drivers = truckDrivers };

        TruckManyDriversDTO dto = query.Select(a => new TruckManyDriversDTO() { Id = a.Truck.Id, Drivers = a.Drivers } ).Single();

        return dto;
    }
```